# How do you look past a picture?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used to think *look past* just means *ignore* until I heard this sentence used by an American talking about a picture saying,

> "If you look past the picture, you can see a horse."

I gave it an online search and the related pages show hidden 3D pictures. I can tell then the picture he was talking about was one of these. The thing I'm not clear about is how you do it. How do you look past a picture exactly? Is it making the picture closer to your eyes or vice versa? Is it looking at the picture from sides? or something else?!

Comment: is this a question from someone whose native language is not English?

Comment: @mobileink when you say _a question from someone_, do you mean _that someone's asking a question_ or _somebody else is asking that someone a question_? in other words, _from_ here means _coming from_ or _meant to be asked someone_?

Comment: you said you heard an American say something.so are you asking because American English is not your native language (so you need informants)?  it makes a difference in how we interpret the question.

Comment: @mobileink it's common to mention where you heard or saw the language being used while asking a question and no i'm not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you look at an object normally, you look at it with both eyes.  Each eye has a line of sight, and those lines of sight cross at the object's surface.  Looking *at* the picture means that the crossing point is on the picture's surface.

[image]
<sub>[[Source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autostereogram#/media/File:Autostereogram_normal_vergence.png)</sub>
<sub>Eyes converge on the surface of the image</sub>

Looking *past* an object means that the lines of sight cross *behind* the object.  If you can get your lines of sight to cross at the right distance past the surface of one of these special pictures, there is an illusion of a 3-D image.  This happens because these special pictures are repetitive, and focusing on the right distance past the picture's surface makes the repetitions line up.  Small differences in the repetitions create the 3-D illusion.

[image]
<sub>[[Source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autostereogram#/media/File:Autostereogram_wall-eyed_vergence.png)</sub>
<sub>Eyes converge **past** the surface of the image</sub>

Comment: In this particular case we're dealing with a context significantly different to *figurative* usages such as *If you look past the raw data you'll see [something more profound]*. In practice, because that figurative usage is *so* common, and because lots of people actually have trouble even *understanding* the "magic eye" context, let alone *doing* the "defocusing", I think it's probably more common to use *If you **focus** past the [autostereogram] picture, you'll see something in 3d*. But we rarely use ***focus*** like that for my figurative example.

Comment: +1 I see. Thank you. @FumbleFingers and thank you for the additional information.

Comment: [magiceye.com](http://www.magiceye.com/faq_example.htm) "Focus as though you are looking *through* the image into the distance."

Comment: For a related example perhaps, if you look past the pictures of some [Giuseppe Arcimboldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Arcimboldo) paintings, you can see portraits instead of just fruits/vegetables/animals

Comment: Contrary to what @1006a says, your virtual image (reflection) in a shop window is at about the same distance as the goods on display.  The relevant surface is the writing (if any) on the glass, which is midway between your real eyes and your reflected eyes.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @AntonSherwood. It's been many years since I was learning to do this! For clarity's sake, I'll delete the wrong instructions and make a new comment with the correct ones.

Comment: You can practice this when window shopping. First, look at the surface of the glass—at any smudges or dust or writing on the glass. That is equivalent to focusing on the surface of the picture. Then focus through the window at the items on display. That is the equivalent of looking past the surface of the picture, to focus on the hidden 3D image. You can also use a mirror, focusing first on the surface of the mirror (smudges, etc.) and then *through the looking glass* at your own reflection. If you get used to what this change in focus feels like, it will be easier to see the "magic" pictures.

Answer (score 4):

Look past doesn't always mean 'ignore'.  It can also mean 'look beyond'. If there's a building in the foreground of my field of view, and a tree in the background, then I can say:

> If you look past the building you'll see a maple tree.

Comment: Just to be sure we're on the same page, I'm talking about a **hidden** 3D picture. You see these pictures that in the first look you just see random lines and colors. So if you look past these pictures you should try to find a way to see beyond these random patterns. So look past doesn't say anything about the positioning of your eyes or the picture, it just simply means **try to see beyond**. Am I right?

Comment: Yes.  The hidden 3D picture thing is a special case that we don't have specific words for in English.